# Selecting a parent directory in html

Tags: html, directory, parent

I have a general question (I'm not all to familiar with html).

The following use of the slash I have discovered points to a sub-directory, in this case for Images:

```
/Image/my_Image.png
```

Is there an html equivalent for pointing to a parent directory?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

`../` will give you one level higher parent directory. You can use as much as you want to go higher level parents like `../../`

```
../Image/my_Image.png
```

will be Image folder in parent directory

Answer (score 31):

Single dot = current directory, double dot is parent directory...

```
./ = current
../ = parent
```

So let's say you have a style rule for an image in a CSS file called "styles.css".

- The location of the stylesheet is C:\MyApp\CSS\styles.css.
- The location of the image is: C:\MyApp\Image\my_Image.png.

When the CSS is being read, it will be **the location of that css file that's used for the current location**. So if you want to get to your image, you can point it like this:

```
background: url("../Image/my_Image.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
```

If the location of the image would have been directly on C:\, you would have to go back two parent directories:

```
background: url("../../my_Image.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
```

This principle also goes for JavaScript files and so on.

Answer (score 13):

It works perfectly also together with a `<base>` tag;

example

```
<head>
<base href="resources\">
</head>
```

then from the root index: `<a href="template\sample1.html">sample1</a>`

```
<head>
<base href="..\resources\">
</head>
```

then from the template: `<img src="images\sample1.jpg">`

working with a directory structure like:

> index.html
>     resources\template\
>     resources\images\